# path to subfolder for a text file

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
StreamReader content1 = File.OpenText("../DATA/heading.txt");
```

I have a txt file in a subfolder called DATA, I am trying to access this file from code but the code goes to the .net runtime directitory and not the application directory, thanks for the help

Comment: What kind of process this? Is it running under IIS ?

Answer (score 4):

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("/Data/heading.txt");
StreamReader content1 = File.OpenText(filePath);
```

Comment: If your Data folder is in the root of your web application I might suggest to add a tilda ~ to the relative path. Server.MapPath("~/Data/heading.txt"); because a tilda represents the application root.

Comment: That's correct, and is important if your site is in a virtual directory, if not '/' will always be the root directory.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Application's Entry assembly to get your text file path like this.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
string appDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.Location);
string filePath = Path.Combine(appDir, "../DATA/heading.txt");
StreamReader content1 = File.OpenText(filePath);
```

This will work for any application that starts as an exe.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext.aspx

The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory. To obtain the current working directory, see GetCurrentDirectory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx

So your current directory is not set to your application directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since you marked this as asp.net are you looking on the server from asp.net?  If so try Server.MapPath http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx